# How to kill my own Activity - the hard way

Tags: android, process, android-activity, kill

So I have my Activity, and on pressing a "Quit" button I call Activity.finish(). This effectively closes my application.

The problem: The Dalvik-process of my application is still hanging around as a zombie in background. It seems like this is normal as other applications do the same. Even The hello-world example hangs around in memory..

I could live with this, but unfortunatley this behaviour makes the development of my application a pain. I have a remote service connected to my Activity, and this service won't unload until my Activity unloads (which as said it never does).

Everything is somehow kept alive for no good reason.

How can I *really* remove my Activity from memory?

I'm looking for something like Activity.finish_and_kill_my_process_please() call or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So I have my Activity, and on pressing
>   a "Quit" button I call
>   Activity.finish(). This effectively
>   closes my application.

[Please don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238).

> The Dalvik-process of my application
>   is still hanging around as a zombie in
>   background.

The process is kept in a cache, for potential reuse by Android. You can safely ignore it.

> I have a remote service connected to
>   my Activity, and this service won't
>   unload until my Activity unloads
>   (which as said it never does).

You probably have a bug in your application, such as calling `startService()` and failing to call `stopService()`, or calling `bindService()` and failing to call `unbindService()`.

Answer (score 26):

1. Call ***finish();*** on button click
2. Add this line to onDestroy method:

***android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());***

```
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

Comment: For a released app KillProcess() isn't a good idea. But for the development phase (speeding up termination of an app for debugging purposes) this is a life saver. +1.

Comment: Definitely Useful while developing(for temporary use)

Comment: This has been useful to help me to unload a native lib :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [`killBackgroundProcesses`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("name.of.your.package");
```

You will need to add the [`KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES) permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Ok, well it appears this method is no longer part of the ActivityManager class??

Comment: There is a new API for Android 2.2 Froyo but this is a VERY bad idea. That permissions is marked as DANGEROUS and users will see that your app has the ability to kill other apps.

Comment: While terminating an app's process is almost never a good idea outside of obscure tests during development, this is an unnecessarily roundabout way to do it.  A process can simply exit() or kill itself - it doesn't need to ask the ActivityManager to do so.

Answer (score 5):

By killing the process you can stop the application completely.from the last screen on back button press you can kill the process by :

```
public void onBackPressed() {   
        super.onBackPressed();   
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if not only activity, but also the application you want to terminate, you can use

`System.exit(0)`

People say that it's deprecated or bad example, but, well it's pure Java and does work...

Comment: Do you know why people say those things?  Does it have something to do with how the application "lives" within the Android O.S.?  This is tempting to use in one of my apps.. but I'd like to know the theory behind the discouragement first.

Comment: Well, I think they say it because Android can manage applications itself; so we shouldn't poke our nose in. I say this is bullsh*t though: If it's my application, who else but me can know when to terminate it? :)

Comment: System.exit is not equivalent to killing a process and may resume any activities on the activity stack that have been paused. See here for more: https://proandroiddev.com/a-cautionary-tale-on-android-do-not-call-system-exit-5279e0d5dbe0

Comment: Thanks @SullX! I guess this is a good example on why it's not recommended :) It seems Android can restart the application if there are 'unfinished' activities left after System.exit() call... Didn't know about this at all! :)

Answer (score 0):

By using the ActivityManager we can close the another applications also.

```
private ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.restartPackage("com.jimmy.appToBeClosed");
```

to use the above code should have the `android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGE` permissions in manifest file.

Comment: restartPackage is now deprecated. use killBackgroundProcesses instead.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the System.exit(0) on the Java side, you can also call a native method during onDestroy which calls exit(0) on the C/C++ side. This seems to force the lib to exit completely. It's working for me!

Answer (score -1):

System.exit() instantly unloads whole virtual machine with all native libraries, services and etc.