# can't stop my app

Tags: android

I have an app with one activity that I can't seem to stop.  I have a button on it that executes finish().  Whether I use that or I use the back button on the phone the app continues to run.

I see it's still running by tapping on it in Applications and the Force Stop button is enabled.

What might be causing this?
Thanks, Gary

Comment: This has already been covered before see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241322/android-howto-kill-my-own-activity-the-hard-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suicide (Option 1)

1. Call ***finish();*** on button click
2. Add this line to onDestroy method:

***android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());***

```
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

---

## Suicide (Option 2)

Call this in the button listener

```
System.exit (0);
```

Comment: oops, the killprocess also killed my service which I wanted to keep running!

Comment: @user1058647 'cause the service and the activity run in a single process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to stop your activity/app instead of finish(),

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```