# Activity UI modification not working?

Tags: java, android

I've one class controller.This class is a public interface and contains all the methods that i can execute from my Activity.Following is my controller class:

```
    public class Controller {
    private Activity activity;
    private TextView parentView;

    public Controller(Activity activity,Textview view) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.parentView=view;

}

public void initialize(String app, String rel) {
    this.app = app;
    this.rel = rel;
    Controller.controller = new LibraryController(activity,
                this);
    Controller.controller.initialize(app, rel);
}

public void libraryInitialised() {

parentView.setText("in library initiliase");

}
```

}

In Library controller there is a Asynctask that parse the Web Service and post execute of Asynctask executes the library initialized method of controller class.

I am calling controller class from my android project as:

```
  Textview view=(TextView)FindViewbyId(someid);

  Controller controller=new Controller(viewCallingActivity.this,view);

  controller.initialize("appname","3.4.0");
```

Now the problem is If I run this small App from eclipse on my device it works very well and gives me a message "in library initialize" in a device but when i opens it from launcher icon it does not gives me the message "in library initialize"

I don't know exactly what's the problem ?

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Is it just a typo that you have a variable `v` you initialize and `view` you provide to the controller?

Comment: @KarolGusak:It was my mistake while writing question.i have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close your installed app - hard way by app manager (Force stop) on your device and then launch it again. Your method may not be called because, when you are closing `Activity` by 'back button' the Dalvik-process of application is still hanging around in background for potential reuse by Android. If this is a reason I suggest you to read this question and answers 

[How to kill my own Activity - the hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241322/how-to-kill-my-own-activity-the-hard-way)